# UITableViewCell subclass doesn't let me set label text

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, subclass

I made a subclass of `UITableViewCell` to get a bigger TableViewCell with some more options.

But my problem is that I can't set the text(s) of the label(s):

```
BlogItem *bi = [[channel items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

NSLog(@"%@", [bi title]);
[[cell mainLabel] setText:[bi title]];
NSLog(@"%@", [[cell mainLabel] text]);
```

The first log message returns the text I expected, but the second one always logs (null).

I really don't know what should be wrong.  I've created the labels as usual:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mainLabel;
```

Of course I connected the labels and synthesized them (checked it twice).  I've also implemented the method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to get the appropriate height for each cell (which works fine).

BTW, checkmarks appear as expected. It's just about the labels.

Comment: Looks to me like **cell** is **nil**.  Try logging that first to make sure you actually have a cell object.

Comment: Have you attached label Outlet with cell...in xib file??? If yes then check your cell, either its nil???

Comment: The cell exists:
For example:
<BlogTableViewCell: 0x6ad1730; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 362; 320 117); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x6ad0140>>

Comment: But the label itself ([cell mainLabel]) is nil. How can i allocate it ? It is a weak reference.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are instantiating your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Also make sure that those `IBOutlets` are declared in your `UITableView` subclass and NOT in the View Controller that houses the `TableView`.  Also make sure that the parent class of your cell in interface builder is set to that same subclass.

Something like this (Custom `UITableViewCell` subclass interface file):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *mainLabel;
@end
```

Then `@synthesize` in the implementation file:

```
@synthesize mainLabel;
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, something like:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";
MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

BlogItem *bi = [[channel items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

// Configure the cell...
cell.mainLabel.text = [bi title];
// ... Other stuff
return cell;
```

Comment: Well, my code already looks like this. The only difference is that you declared the IBOutlet as strong. When I learned programming I was told to always set IBOutlets up as weak propertys.
I've changed it now to strong and initialized them. Now the Text is at least set properly. Thus, it doesn't display anything.